# What is the difference between predicate-argument structure and case structure

Tags: semantics, cases, phrase-structure

Predicate's arguments are just case slots, aren't they? So predicate-argument structure and case structure are just the same thing?

Comment: In predicate calculus case has to be specified, along with everything else. `V` (`NP`, `NP`), for instance, specifies that the first `NP` argument is the grammatical subject of `V`, and the second one is the grammatical direct object (in non-ergative languages, anyway; for ergative languages you're on your own). It is of course also possible to formalize case grammar directly without resorting to predicate calculus.

Comment: @jlawler My understanding is that, take *John had a meal* for example, predicate-argument structure is like `[sub:NP:John] [pred:VP:had] [obj:NP:a meal]`, and case structure is like `had(John, a meal)`. They are just the same thing in different form? Am I right?

Comment: These are formal descriptions, so they **can't** be "the same thing in different form". Different form is **different** in formal grammar, unless there's an identity proof. So it depends on the axioms of the formal theory you're using; the forms may be equivalent, or one may include the other, or they may have overlapping truth sets, or they may be disjoint. Or something more complicated.

Comment: @jlawler Could you please show me some examples respectively? I am just still little confused. thank you~

Comment: It might be that the theory designer had developed conventions for indicating grammatical relations like subject/direct object/indirect object, or case relations like agent/patient/receiver (these are not the same relations; though they often match in practice, transformations often change them); if so, then they are there to be followed. If not, you can make your own conventions; ask your teacher what theory this is and what notational conventions are common. It's kinda like upgrading a browser and learning new shortcuts.